# PHP and JS test

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, session-variables

I need to test a value in the client side, using js, before the content is loaded. Then, I want to give this value to PHP, which then should show the appropriate content depending on the value. The way I am doing it, is by posting via $.post of jquery, obtaining the value with a PHP function, storing it in $_SESSION and displaying the appropriate content.

However, since I am using $_SESSION, if the client side value changes, it requires two refreshes to show the correct content (because it looks like when jQuery is posting, it keeps loading the content and the new $_SESSION value is already late).

Should I use $_SESSION? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can't you just return the value to the $.post call and use jQuery to change the content dynamically?

Comment: What client side data are you after that would necessitate a change of content from the server?

Comment: This is a knife through my 'progressive enhancement' heart.

Comment: I agree with @dave, also your session should be above your output-ted content.

Comment: I have to do it from php because the content that I need to load comes from server... If i do it directly from javascript I cannot bring php values to the page.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use $.get of jquery and request the page with variables passed to it using traditional GET method.

Javascript side:

```
fetch "./data.php?param1=value1&param2=value2"
```

PHP Side:

```
$param1=$_GET['param1'];
$param2=$_GET['param2'];
use it and compile the html.
```